# function to create a modal without self._getCurrentPage();

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I'm trying to create a function to popup a modal, currently on one of my functions I'm taking the current URL to popup my modal my function is this that is working nicely

```
imgSettings.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var pageName = self._getCurrentPage();
    var modal = (self.modal());
    var content = "<iframe width='100%' height='400' frameborder='2' scrolling='yes' allowtransparency='true' \n\
                             src='../help/help_" + pageName + "'></iframe>";
    $('#jsn-pos-left').hide();
    modal.open({
        content: content
    });
});
```

but i want to accomplish without the `self._getCurrentPage();` and just to manually have a page here that is somewhere in a directory of my project...

how can i do that?

please i will really appreciate any help

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  it was very simple....
  just change
   from
      var content = "<iframe width='100%' height='400' frameborder='2' scrolling='yes'   allowtransparency='true' \n\
                            src='../help/help_" + pageName + "'></iframe>";
      to smthing like this....
      var content = "<iframe width='100%' height='400' frameborder='2' scrolling='yes' allowtransparency='true' \n\
                            src='../help/help_versionSoftware.html'></iframe>";

  thnk you
```